# How can I preserve the logs a docker/podman container even after the container dies?

Tags: logs, docker, podman, openshift

I have pods running in OpenShift that I would like to view the logs for. In particular, I want to see the logs when the pod is terminated.

However, when the pod is terminated the logs are deleted as far as I can tell. I've tried tailing 'oc logs ' but I lose the output once the pod is gone.

What is a clean way to copy these logs in real time or print them to stdout so that they will persist after the pod is killed?

Comment: If I understood correctly the I assume you are running docker commands with `docker run --rm` (`--rm` this deletes the container). Maybe while the container is running you can use something like: `docker logs --details --follow id_container > /tmp/id_container.logs`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to associate a [persistent volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to the pod and to redirect the log file to this volume.

Another way is to use a log collector such as [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) and the [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack) stack to index and visualize them.

You can also use the cluster-level [OpenShift logging infrastructure](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/4.12/html/logging/cluster-logging).